# Replace duplex switch with swith/outlet? Swith will control ceiling fan w/ lamp

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m replacing this damaged duplex switch with this switch/outlet:

Old duplex switch:
[image]

New switch/outlet combination:
[image][image]As you can see from the old wiring, the blue and red wires are connected to one side of the switch, the black wire is connected to the other side, and the white wire is not connected to anything.

I don’t trust whoever did this installation, so I go to the experts.

Can a switch/outlet replace a duplex switch? If so, how do I wire this switch/outlet correctly?

I’ll be installing a ceiling fan with a lamp. I’m including pics of the wires from the fan, and pics from the wires in the ceiling.

Fan
[image]

[image]

Ceiling wiring
[image]

Comment: I have to say, your new switch does _not_ look much like a switch. Are you intending to have an outlet/recepticle there or did you grab a random internet image of the wrong thing?

Comment: Nope. The new one is the one I bought at true value.

Comment: How'd you buy a receptacle instead of a switch?

Comment: Just realized I took a picture of the wrong thing. I’ll delete the question.

Comment: Do you want two separate switches here still? What's with the new thing being a switch-outlet?

Comment: The switch used to turn on a fan with a lightbulb, so I’m not sure why a dual switch was installed in the first place.

Comment: Since there’s one plug in the room, I thought that it would help to have one switch that turns the fan on/off and a plug.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the fan then please? I think I get where you're going here, just want to make sure :)

Comment: I posted one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjTal.jpg

Comment: @rbhat -- that's the box for the switch, I need to know what's in the box for the fan itself

Comment: Are you saying dismantling the fan?

Comment: @rbhat -- taking the fan down but not unwiring it

Comment: I took pictures of the wires coming from the fan, and wires in the ceiling.

Comment: How do you want to control the fan and light?

Comment: The new unit only has one switch (the other’s a plug) so the easiest would be that the switch controls the power to the fan and light.

Answer (score 1):

### This isn't terribly hard now that we know what it is we want here

The good news is that you look to have all the necessary wires in place, save for a grounding pigtail to the back of the box since this is a conduit job and your switch-receptacle lacks self-grounding clips.  The bad news is it'll require a bit of pigtailing to wire this up, so you'll need a wirenut suitable for 3 12AWG wires and a couple of short (3-6") lengths of black 12AWG stranded THHN.

First off, we prepare the box by using the 10-32 screw on our grounding pigtail to attach it to the 10-32 tapped hole in the back of the box; if there is no such hole, then you can drive a Garvin GSST into the back of the box and use that to attach your grounding pigtail.

We then can move onto preparing the switch-receptacle; one of the black pigtails is attached to COM, while the other is attached to L1.  Once that's done, we can start wiring up the receptacle.  The grounding pigtail goes to one of the grounding terminals on the device, while the white wire gets untaped and connected to a neutral terminal on the receptacle part.  One of the black pigtails from the switch section goes into one of the line terminals on the receptacle portion, while the black wire from the wall goes into the other line terminal on the receptacle end.  Finally, the other black pigtail gets nutted with the red and blue wires from the wall.

Once all that's done, you can button up the box, turn the breaker back on, and enjoy your new switch-outlet!